# Firestore Listeners Best Practices While Updating My UI

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Do I need to put my Firestore listeners in my View Controller or can I put them in a model class? Based on my research, best practices is apparently to keep the database code within separate models.

However, I need to update my UI based on database changes.

That means I should at least attach the listeners within my View Controllers and not in the model, correct?

Or am I violating best practices here?

Blessings.

Tai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to put your listener on your viewController or you can create another class like singleton contains listener methods and with it's methods update the Ui.This also reduce the rewriting of the same code.